# Migration from SQL SERVER 2008 R2 to 2019 with Log Shipping

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, log-shipping, sql-server-2019

Is possible to run swing migration from SQL SERVER 2008 R2 to 2019 with Log Shipping?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible.

You can migrate databases from older versions like SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2019.

Check answer from here. [Migrate to SQL Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15)

> Log shipping: Log shipping is supported if primary is running SQL
> Server 2008 SP3 or later, or SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 or later, and
> secondary is running SQL Server 2019.
>
> Warning:  If an automatic or manual failover happens and the SQL
> Server 2019 instance becomes primary, SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server
> 2008 R2 instance becomes secondary and cannot receive changes from
> primary.